# How to get hours value greater than 24 hours in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

```
time1 = timedelta(days=2, hours=6.20)
time2 = timedelta(hours=20.10)
sum_time = time1 + time2
print str(sum_time)
print sum_time.total_seconds() / 3600
```

Output:

```
3 days, 2:18:00
74.3
```

How to get output **74:18:00** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `total_Seconds / 3600` you only get the hours in decimal format.

You can use [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) to break down the seconds into full hours, minutes and seconds:

> divmod(a, b)
>
> Take two (non complex) numbers as arguments and return a pair of numbers consisting of their quotient and remainder when using long division

The code would look like this (I added 34 seconds in time2 to check if the seconds part is correct):

```
from datetime import timedelta
time1 = timedelta(days=2, hours=6.20)
time2 = timedelta(hours=20.10, seconds=34)
sum_time = time1 + time2
print str(sum_time)
hours, seconds = divmod(sum_time.total_seconds(), 3600)
minutes,  seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
print "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hours, minutes, seconds)
```

and the output will be:

```
3 days, 2:18:34
74:18:34
```

The result of the first `divmod` is 74 hours (quotient) and a remainder of 1114 seconds.
The second `divmod` is feeded with the remaining seconds from the line before (1114) and gives a result of 18 minutes and 34 seconds.